# Creating a dropdown with data from multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a dropdown of Vendors. I have a Vendors table in my DB, containing a VendorID and a CompanyID. The Company table contains a CompanyID and a Name.

I would like to have a dropdown with items that have the VendorID as the value and the Company Name as the text. But I don't know how to get the Name field from the related table to put in the dropdown, so I have the VendorID as the value and text. Here's what I have right now.

I'm passing in a model that contains this:

```
public IEnumerable<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
```

In my controller, I'm setting the value of Vendors like this:

```
MyDBEntities _entities = new MyDBEntities();
Vendors = _entities.Vendors;
```

Here is my dropdown list on the page:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VendorId, new SelectList(Model.Vendors, "VendorID", "VendorID"), "- Select a Vendor -")%>
```

I thought I could create a custom function - GetVendorsForDropdown - that would return only the data I needed, and changing my model to contain `IEnumerable<Something>`. But I don't know what the return type should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use linq and return them as ListItem's

```
MyDBEntities _entities = new MyDBEntities();
var data = from v in _entities.Vendors
           from c in _entities.Companies
           where v.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
           select new ListItem{Value = v.VendorId, Text = c.CompanyName};

return data;
```

Comment: What's the best way to do that? The only way I know of is to load all the Vendors into a List, than enumerate over each one and add it to a List of ListItems. Seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 3):

join the tables and return a collection of ListItems

```
MyDBEntities _entities = new MyDBEntities();
var results = from v in _entities.Vendors
              join c in _entities.Companies on v.CompanyId equals c.CompanyId
              select new ListItem{Value = v.VendorId, Text = c.Name};

return results;
```